# How to display random parts of a page on refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I were to have a block of html coding that is stylized via css such as this:

```
<title>Test Title 1</title>
<p>Test Paragraph 1<p>
<a href="test link1">test link 1</a>
<title>Test Title 2</title>
<p>Test Paragraph 2<p>
<a href="test link2">test link 2</a>
<title>Test Title 3</title>
<p>Test Paragraph 3<p>
<a href="test link3">test link 3</a>
```

I want to be able to display a set of parts randomly together, (i.e. title 1, paragraph 1 and link 1 only). Then if I refresh it randomly shows 1, 2 or 3. But they need to stay together, like parts of 1 cannot show with part of 3 and so on.

I know this is simple, but I can't figure out how to get them to show randomly together.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share what have tried so far?

Comment: If they need to stay together, it would be better to group them together in a `<div>` element; also, you should only have *one* `<title>` element and it should be in `<head>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to group all related parts together.  See the HTML below.  Note that title tags were replaced with heading tags.  The title should be in the header of the page.

```
<section>
    <h2>Test Title 1</h2>
    <p>Test Paragraph 1</p>
    <a href="test link1">test link 1</a>
</section>
<section>
    <h2>Test Title 2</h2>
    <p>Test Paragraph 2</p>
    <a href="test link2">test link 2</a>
</section>
<section>
    <h2>Test Title 3</h2>
    <p>Test Paragraph 3</p>
    <a href="test link3">test link 3</a>
</section>
```

Then, in CSS you need to hide them:

```
section {
    display: none;
}
```

And, here's jQuery stuff:

```
$("section").eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)).css("display", "block");
```

Here's jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Aej52/

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle for this solution please?

Comment: See the updated code and here's jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Aej52/.  Keep in mind that jQuery's eq() function's input is a 0-based index.

Comment: P.S.  Whenever possible always let the browser do most of the work.

Answer (score 0):

use [jquery appendTo method](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)

html code:

```
<div id = " titleBox">
</div>
```

put this javascript in onload event or document ready

test link set yourself

```
function showTitle(){
   var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
   $("<title>Test Title "+rand+"</title>
      <p>Test Paragraph "+rand+"<p>
      <a href=\"test link\">test link "+rand+"</a>"
    ).appendTo("#titleBox");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain javascript version - no jquery, with [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/whVZL/)

### HTML

```
<title>Test Title 1</title>
<!-- correctly close paragraph tags -->
<p>Test Paragraph 1</p>
<a href="test link1">test link 1</a>
<title>Test Title 2</title>
<p>Test Paragraph 2</p>
<a href="test link2">test link 2</a>
<title>Test Title 3</title>
<p>Test Paragraph 3</p>
<a href="test link3">test link 3</a>
```

### Javascript

```
// get references to elements in question, and store them...
var titles = document.getElementsByTagName("title");
var ps = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var as = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

// every now and then, run a function...
setInterval(function(){
    // set all elements to display none
    for(i=0;i<ps.length;i++){
        // add one to offset page title - not part of demo code
        titles[i+1].style.display = "none";
        as[i].style.display = "none";
        ps[i].style.display = "none";
    };
    // choose a lucky winner...
    var choice = Math.floor(Math.random()*(ps.length));
    // make the randomly chosen index item show...
    as[choice].style.display = "block";
    ps[choice].style.display = "block";
    // add one to offset page title - not part of demo code
    titles[choice+1].style.display = "block";
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to generate the elements via JavaScript:

http://jsfiddle.net/qmM36/

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var data = [
        {
            h1: 'Test Title 1',
            p: 'Test Paragraph 1',
            a: { href: '#test-link1', text: 'Test Link 1' }
        },
        {
            h1: 'Test Title 2',
            p: 'Test Paragraph 2',
            a: { href: '#test-link2', text: 'Test Link 2' }
        },
        {
            h1: 'Test Title 3',
            p: 'Test Paragraph 3',
            a: { href: '#test-link3', text: 'Test Link 3' }
        }
    ];
    //-- select an item at random
    var index = Math.floor( Math.random() * data.length );
    var item  = data[index];
    //-- create the HTML elements
    var $placeholder = $('#placeholder');
    $('<h1>').text(item.h1).insertAfter($placeholder);
    $('<p>').text(item.p).insertAfter($placeholder);
    $('<a>').attr('href', item.a.href).text(item.a.text).insertAfter($placeholder);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

In this example, I used a placeholder `div` to mark where the items would be inserted.