# Display Title, URL and Image on Refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I'm borrowing the solution from Robert (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1200182/robert-messerle) on this question.
[How to display random parts of a page on refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399173/how-to-display-random-parts-of-a-page-on-refresh)

However, I'd like to also add an image to each of the element lists. How can the solution be updated to do so?

JS

```
$(function () {
    var data = [
        {
            h1: 'Test Title 1',
            p: 'Test Paragraph 1',
            a: { href: '#test-link1', text: 'Test Link 1' }
        },
        {
            h1: 'Test Title 2',
            p: 'Test Paragraph 2',
            a: { href: '#test-link2', text: 'Test Link 2' }
        },
        {
            h1: 'Test Title 3',
            p: 'Test Paragraph 3',
            a: { href: '#test-link3', text: 'Test Link 3' }
        }
    ];
    //-- select an item at random
    var index = Math.floor( Math.random() * data.length );
    var item  = data[index];
    //-- create the HTML elements
    var $placeholder = $('#placeholder');
    $('<h1>').text(item.h1).insertAfter($placeholder);
    $('<p>').text(item.p).insertAfter($placeholder);
    $('<a>').attr('href', item.a.href).text(item.a.text).insertAfter($placeholder);
});
```

HTML"

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Comment: Can't you just add an img key with a src attribute to each data element, kind of like you do with the a tag?  Then add 1 insertAfter line to insert the image.

Answer (score 1):

u can edit each data element like this:

```
{
    h1: 'Test Title 3',
    p: 'Test Paragraph 3',
    a: { href: '#test-link3', text: 'Test Link 3' },
    img: { src: '/1.jpg' }
}
```

then use this at end of ur js code:

```
  $('<img>').attr('src', item.img.src).insertAfter($placeholder);
```